# Countdown timer is not working correctly

Tags: java, android, timer, countdowntimer

I have a countdown timer that fetches the value of my time picker, and starts counting down when I set the time picker, but what is happening is that It is not counting down to the present time at which you set the time picker. My question is how can I get my countdown timer to countdown to the present time.

Here is my code...

```
   TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        timer = new CounterClass((minute * 60 * 1000) + (hourOfDay * 60 * 60 * 1000), 1000);
        long millis = (minute * 60 *1000) + (hourOfDay * 60 * 60 *1000);
        String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
        System.out.println(hms);
        textViewTime.setText(hms);
        timer.start();

    }
};


public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {

    /**
     * @param millisInFuture    The number of millis in the future from the call
     *                          to {@link #start()} until the countdown is done and {@link #onFinish()}
     *                          is called.
     * @param countDownInterval The interval along the way to receive
     *                          {@link #onTick(long)} callbacks.
     */

    public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        long millis = millisUntilFinished;
        String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
        System.out.println(hms);
        textViewTime.setText(hms);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString(hms, hms);
        Intent mainActivity = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        mainActivity.putExtras(b);



    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

    }
}
```

Thanks:)

Comment: It seems that you're converting the hours and minutes to milliseconds and you're setting the interval to seconds. Try this: `timer = new CounterClass((minute * 60) + (hourOfDay * 60 * 60), 1000);`

Comment: That still doesn't work I'm not sure whats going on. If I set the time picker more than an hour ahead The countdown time is off

Comment: If anyone knows how to do this correctly please post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the difference between the current time and the time that was selected, you can do that using something like this:

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int totalMinutesSelected = (hourOfDay * 60) + minute;
    int totalMinutesNow =(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 60) + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int seconds = (totalMinutesSelected - totalMinutesNow) * 60;
    timer = new CounterClass(seconds, 1000);
    ...
}
```

and in the `CounterClass` class, you will have to do something like this;

```
public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    ...

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() + millisUntilFinished);
        String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE), c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @Leyton I've edited my answer, see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Well now it has stopped counting down at all lol this is peculiar

Comment: @Leyton Are you sure you've included the `textViewTime.setText(hms);` statement in the `onTick(....)` method ?

Comment: yes it pulls up a number which is wrong, and then still doesn't countdown. I honestly have no idea whats wrong